# vimeo api - play-event doesn't always work, any workarounds possible?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I found a bug in the Vimeo javascript API and put an example of it on jsfiddle (see the very end of this post for the link and the code (stackoverflow insists on pasting code along with jsfiddle)

I told Vimeo about it, but they never told me if they could duplicate the bug, or if there was any workaround I could use.

So I'm posting a description of the problem below (you can see the code and run it at jsfiddle), and if you have any ideas (is it really a vimeo bug as opposed to my bug, is there some sequence of calls I can do to defeat the problem) then please let me know.

Here is the description:

The Bug can be described as: “play-event only fires a fraction of the time it is supposed to fire”

Steps to reproduce:

1. run jsfiddle.  The video will play for a few milliseconds and the stop.  An alert will pop up with the words “play-event’, to indicate that the play-event, as expected, fired.
2. pause the video
3. play the video.
4. You will see an alert: “play event fired” every time you play the video.
5. pause the video again.
6. Click the NEXT button.  This button will seek to a position in the middle of the video (actually it is using an array with 4 positions, so the first time you seek, you go to the first position, the next time you seek, you go to the second position, etcetera)
7. The video will jump to a section in the middle.   The video will start playing.  The BUG APPEARS HERE.  The alert that indicates ‘play-event’ was entered should appear.  But it does not!
8. CLUE:  If you don’t click the NEXT button at all until the video has played to almost the end, and THEN you click the NEXT button, you might get lucky, and the ‘play-event’ DOES FIRE!!!!!  My guess is that when the video is mostly cached on the user computer, then the API works better

   https://jsfiddle.net/3f9z7ffo/

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var globalcount = 0;
       var windowwidth = 0;

       var initialseek = true;
       var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
       var timeoutID;
       var stoparray = new Array("48", "103.979", "346.513", "407.459");
       var quiz = false;

       var startPosition = 0;
       var stoplength = stoparray.length;
       var stopindex = -1;
       var timeinterval = 10;
       var defaultwidth = 3;
       var gDuration;
       var gPlayer;
       var gvideowidth;
       var gvideoheight;
       var hiderank;
       var gPlayer;
       var vimeoPlayers;

   </script>
   ```

   ```
   <center>

       <table>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:33%;text-align:right;padding-right:14px"></td>
               <td style="width:33%">
                   <div id="HoldPlayer" style="position:relative">
                       <iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/152639172?autoplay=0&api=1&player_id=player1'
                               id='player1'
                               width='640' height='360'
                               frameborder='0'></iframe>
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td style="width:33%"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>

       <table style="width:100%">
           <tr>
               <td style="text-align:center">
                   Window (total time in seconds): <input type="text" id="windowwidth" maxlength="3" style="width: 30px;" />
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="chkplayvid" />Play</label>
               </td>
           </tr>


       </table>

   </center>


   <center>
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td style="text-align:center">
                   <input type="button" id="nextbutton" onclick="nextPlayer(); return (false);" value="Next" />
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td align="center"></td>
           </tr>


       </table>

   </center>

   <div id="oPara"></div>


   <script type="text/javascript">


       // +++++++++++++
       function ready2() {

           setupEventListeners();
           gPlayer.api('getDuration', function (value, player_id) {
               gDuration = value; // this will be set whenever callback fires
               playVideo();
           });

       }
       // +++++++++++++
       function setupEventListeners() {
           gPlayer.addEvent('pause', pauseEvent);
           gPlayer.addEvent('finish', endEvent);
           gPlayer.addEvent('play', playEvent);
       }


       function endEvent() {
           alert("end event!!!");
           gidClearTimeout(timeoutID);
       }
       function pauseEvent() {
           alert("pauseEvent!!!");
           return;
       }
       function playEvent() {
           alert("playEvent!!!");
           globalcount = globalcount + 1;

           if (initialseek) {
               timeoutID = setTimeout(pausePlayer, 60);
               initialseek = false;
           }
           else {
               timeoutID = setTimeout(pausePlayer, windowwidth);
           }
           return;
       }


       $(document).ready(function () {


           $("#windowwidth").val(defaultwidth);
           setTimeout(addReadyEvent, 60);
       });
       // +++++++++++++
       function addReadyEvent() {

           var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
           gPlayer = $f(iframe);
           gPlayer.addEvent('ready', ready2);
       }

       // +++++++++++++
       function showNextButton() {
           $("#nextbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
       }
       // +++++++++++++
       function playVideo() {

           gPlayer.api('play');
           return;
       }
       // +++++++++++++
       function pausePlayer() {

           gPlayer.api('pause');
           $("#nextbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
           return true;
       }

       // +++++++++++++
       function nextPlayer() {
           var startPosition = 0;
           var str = "";
           var prevpos = -5;
           var stopPosition = 0;

           var dur = gDuration;
           windowwidth = 3;
           windowwidth = parseFloat(windowwidth);
           if (isNaN(windowwidth)) {
               windowwidth = defaultwidth;
           }
           if (windowwidth < 1) {
               windowwidth = 1;
           }
           if (windowwidth > 3600) {
               windowwidth = 3600;
           }
           windowwidth = Math.round(windowwidth);
           stopindex = stopindex + 1;


           stopPosition = parseFloat(stoparray[stopindex]);

           if (stopPosition > dur) {
               stopPosition = dur;
           }
           /* was here */

           startPosition = parseInt(stopPosition - windowwidth, 10);


           gPlayer.api('seekTo', startPosition);
           gPlayer.api('pause');
           setTimeout(playVideo, 60);

           return false;
       }

   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo did answer - one workaround is, assuming your video is paused, to first call 'play' and after that call 'seek', and then the playevent will fire.